# Using struts2-junit-plugin jars with Struts1.x application

Tags: struts2, junit4, struts-1, struts2-junit-plugin

I am working on struts 1.x application and need to implement junit 4 test cases in it.
I have struts2-junit-plugin jars for using StutsTestCase to create test cases for Action classes. Is this possible ? Struts 1.x app using struts2-junit jars . When i am trying to run test case , its giving error - **InitializationError**
When i check failure Trace - its showing
**java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/springframework/core/io/resourceloader**

Can anyone help me with cause . Is it something with version of junit jars or using struts2 jar in struts 1 app. Or i need to add something more or any other mistake. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

This makes no sense--Struts 2 is a *completely* different framework. There is zero overlap in functionality, supporting libraries, architecture, etc.

You *might* be able to rework the Struts 1 `StrutsTestCase` to support any explicitly-JUnit 4 functionality, if it doesn't out-of-the-box, or simply build up the supporting objects (e.g., `ActionForm`, `ActionMapping`, and the normal HTTP stuff) and run "bare" tests.

There's a reason Struts 1 was EOL'd over five years ago: the architecture is antiquated and tightly coupled to itself and to HTTP, which made testing difficult. If you search around you may find some resources for updating the testing infrastructure.

Comment: Hey thanks for input , we are working around to migrate this legacy app to spring mvc now